# Customize comment color in minted style

Tags: minted

I'm using the `minted` package to highlight some Python code, and currently I'm using `\usemintedstyle{trac}`.

I want to change the color of the comment (from the current light brown-ish) to green. My understanding is that you either define a new style and include it in the styles folder of `pygments` or you can change `trac.py` directly.

In `trac.py`, I see:

```
Comment: 'italic #999988',
Comment.Preproc: 'bold noitalic #999999',
Comment.Special: 'bold #999999',
```

However, modiyfing the hex codes above does not seem to affect the color of comments in the output. In fact, the output for comment is not italic at all (which I like) but it is specified as italic here.

So how exactly the styles defined in `pygments` affect the output of `minted` package? Is there something else I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `minted` creates a folder in the current directory and "caches" the styles you are using in there.  If you delete the corresponding file from the folder folder, any changes you make to `trac.py` should then take effect.